# GAE-Python: Can Appstats record RPC made in background thread?

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, webapp2, app-engine-ndb, appstats

I had used Appstats to record my ndb usage in my GAE project, and it worked very well. My Appstats setup was following [this doc](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/appstats).

Recently, I move some ndb code to be executed on background thread, but those ndb calls don't show on Appstats console UI any more.

I have tried Appstats in both the dev and prod, they don't record ndb RPCs made in background thread.

To make the question clear, I means:
Appstats works for:

```
class MyHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def put(self):
        ...
        do_a_lot_of_ndb_work()
        ...
```

but Appstats doesn't work for:

```
class MyHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def put(self):
        ...
        background_thread.start_new_background_thread(do_a_lot_of_ndb_work, [])
        ...
```

Can I change some parameters in appengine_config.py or do something to make Appstats works for both?

**Update**:
The above code snippets are running in backend (basic_scaling, max_instances=1), and the thread usage is referenced from https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/#Python_Background_threads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be using threads this way. The correct way to execute functions that run longer than the 60sec request window is to use the Taskqueue API. That gives you a 10 minute window before the Task times out.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/

If you **really** need to do even more processing than that, look into using backends.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/backends/

If you're looking to run ndb calls asynchronously for performance, the tasklet decorators described here are excellent and highly recommended:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/async

(The newest release of the SDK, 1.8.4, allows you to run transactions in a tasklet as well using the @transactional_tasklet decorator.)

I use all three of those methods for stuff that doesn't need to hold up the main request thread and appstats works well in all those cases.

You should also take a good look at what you're trying to do and see if it can be reasonably split up into smaller chunks, because it's probably going to cost a lot if you need more than 10 minutes to do the processing.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I should mention it in my question, the code snippet is already running in a backend (the modules mode). Do you mean Appstats doesn't record the RPC because MyHandler is finished while the thread is running, so, the RPC happened in thread doesn't be recorded?

Comment: Pretty much. Appstats logs RPCs that are attached to a request handler, through the middleware that you set up in appengine_config.py. Appstats will stop recording as soon as the request handler returns. Since it's running on a backend, you can try letting the request run indefinitely instead of spawning a new thread. Just make sure it handles exits gracefully. ;)

Comment: Thanks for your explanation about the Appstats. It was another story that made me decide spawning new thread on the backend. (non billing enabled project can have at most 2 modules, and I have used 2 modules, and I hope the same backend module can handle multiple requests even if when it is processing long running procedure. That's the reason made me spawning new thread on backend.) After your explanation, I decide to make backend run the long running processing directly, and increase backend max_instances to 2 to handle other request(s) if there exists.